# Enable/Disable Hotkeys in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, hotkeys

I want to temporarily disable all the hotkeys, systemwide. I want to prevent the app to close on cmd+q and instead send an alert while registering a global shortcut.
I tried with

```
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>
@implementation
void *oldHotKeyMode;
-(void)disableHotKeys{
    NSLog(@"disable");
    oldHotKeyMode = PushSymbolicHotKeyMode(kHIHotKeyModeAllDisabled);
}
-(void)enableHotKeys{
    NSLog(@"enable");
    PopSymbolicHotKeyMode(oldHotKeyMode);
}
```

I can see the enable/disable `NSLog` but it doesn't work. Xcode 4.6.3, deployment target OSX10.7, running on 10.8. "Enable access for assistive devices" in System Preferences is thicked.

Edit: my app is sandboxed, I think that this is the problem. Is there an alternative method?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why would you ever want to disable the ability to quit apps through the keyboard shortcut?  I can always just force quit them or go into Activity Monitor and kill them there.

Comment: i repeat: "I want to prevent the app to close on cmd+q and instead send an alert while registering a global shortcut". While registering a global shortcut means that if the user don't know that cmd+w closes the window, instead of closing everything without a reason the app will show an alert that will warn the user. The global shortcuts are disabled only while the user is registering a global shortcut.

Comment: were u able to achieve this?